# Compare some keys from 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to compare the value of the keys from 2 multidimensional arrays :

```php
array1 [
  0 => [
    "designation" => "multiple"
    "type" => "AAAAA"
    "model" => "B"
    "isSim" => false
    "order" => 5
  ]
etc...
]

array2 [
  0 => [
    "designation" => "single"
    "type" => "AACAA"
    "model" => "B"
  ]
etc...
]
```

I would like to compare 'designation', 'type', 'model' from array1 to array2 and if the values are the same, I will set the 'isSim' to true.

I know how to set 'isSim' but I've got some difficulties to compare the 2 multidimensional arrays

NOTE => The 2 arrays don't have the same size

Comment: do you want to compare index basis? i mean index[0] with index[0],index[1] with index[1]....??

Comment: No only 'designation', 'type', 'model' from each arrays

Comment: though your question is not clear, are you trying to do something like this?       for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array1); $i++){
         for($k=0;sizeof($array2); $k++){
            if($array1[$i]['designation'] == $array2[$k]['designation'] && $array1[$i]['type'] == $array2[$k]['type'] && $array1[$i]['model'] == $array2[$k]['model'] ){
               $isSim = 'true';
            }
         }
      }

Comment: You should improve the question with more data. currently we can only guess what you realy wanna do. furthermore: what have your tried so far? what are your approches to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like the following:

```
$basearray = [["designation" => "multiple", 
    "type" => "AAAAA",
    "model" => "B",
    "isSim" => false,
    "order" => 5 ]];

$compareto = [["designation" => "single"
    "type" => "AACAA"
    "model" => "B"]];

foreach($basearray as $base){
    foreach($compareto as $compare){
        if($compare["designation"] == $base["designation"] && 
           $compare["type"] == $base["type"] &&
           $compare["model"] == $base["model"]){
           
           $base["isSim"] = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Additionally if you are sure that there can only be one array in `$compareto` that is the same as an array from `$basearray` you can put a `break;` after `$base["isSim"] = true;`.

Comment: Nice perfect it works thx

Comment: a single for loop is enough :)

Comment: @OMiShah could you explain how?

Comment: you can access the object from each arrays using the $i (or whatever name you give) as: ``if($compareto[$i]["designation"] == $basearray[$i]["designation"])``

Comment: I see, but the arrays are not necessarily the same length so it won't work right?

Comment: Also, even if we assume that they are the same length `$compareto[$i]["designation"]` is not mandatory to match `$basearray[$i]["designation"]`, it could match `$basearray[$i-1]["designation"]` which would never be checked with just one loop